# How explicitly call the standard java classloader implementation for serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, classloader

I'm trying to pass a serialized object from one process to another but it appears as though the classloaders have been changed from the default Java implementation and are conflicting.

How can I create an object from the one process using some standard Java classloader so that I can guarantee consistency?

I've never worked with classloaders in Java before so my understanding here is very limited.

Comment: Serializables declare a serial version uid. When trying to de-serialize an object, this id is checked to make sure the class of the object being de-serialized matches the class of the same name available to the classloader from which the de-serialization happens. The ```.class```  files that are used might be different between the 2 processes.

Comment: You always use the default class loader by default. Can you show us an example which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The work of serialization is not done by classloaders.  In fact, the only involvement that classloaders have are that it *may* be necessary to load a class when deserializing an object of that class ... if the class isn't already loaded.

It is hard to see how changing a classloader could cause problems.  However, it is possible that you could have problems if a class loader was loading the an incompatible version of a class.  That can cause a conflict.  But the root cause is the different class versions, not the different class loaders.

How can you avoid the conflict?  The simple answer is to not change classes when you have serialized instances.  There are ways of dealing with class changes (using custom `readObject` / `writeObject` methods for example) but is better to avoid the problem.

This is one reason why Java object serialization is not a very good mechanism for persisting data.